# HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH error when Content-Length to BytesIO length

Tags: python, pyramid, reportlab

I'm moving a python pyramid project from python 2 to 3. I was using ReportLab to generate PDF files and send it to the front end. According to their examples I need to use `io.BytesIO()`, when previously it was `StringIO()`.

Now using the generated document length to set the `Content-Length` in my response, I get an `HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH` error.

```
pdf = io.BytesIO()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf)
doc.build(story)
pdfcontent = pdf.getvalue()
pdf.close()

response = Response(content_type='application/pdf', body=pdfcontent)
response.headers.add("Content-Length", str(len(pdfcontent)))
```

If I don't set the `Content-Length` attribute the download works fine, but I would rather not leave it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about you particular example and error, but I'm pretty sure that when you provide the response `body` bytes like this, Pyramid sends the `Content-Length` header. No need to set it manually, it already has the bytes and therefore knows its size.

You should check the response headers (using your browser developer tools or a command line tools like curl or httpie).

Comment: Well what do you know, it does get set automatically!